# Is $\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ closed in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Given $S= \{\frac{1}{n} \mid n\in \mathbb{N} \}$
>
> Is  S is  closed in $\mathbb{Q}$?

My attempt :  I think $S$ is not closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ because the limit point $ 0 \notin \mathbb{Q}$

Is this true ?

Comment: yes it is not closed, you can also see that closure of the set in the subspace topology is the closure of the set on $\mathbb{R }$ intersected with the rationals.

Comment: $0$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$ but not in $S$

Comment: @PeterSzilas This is not true. Take $S=(-\infty,\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: @PeterSzilas being closed in a subspace does not imply being closed in the ambient space.

Comment: @Wojowu Or $S = \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @PeterSzilas $\Bbb Q$ is not closed in $\Bbb R$ but its intersection with $\Bbb Q$ is of course closed in $\Bbb Q$. So not true.

Comment: Henno.Thanks. Got it wrong. Started with $A \subset  \mathbb{R}$, and $S$ closed in $\mathbb{R}$, then $S \cap A$ closed in $A$.

Comment: Wowoju.Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0 \in \Bbb Q$ but $0\notin S$ while it **is** a limit point of $S$. So $S$ does not contain all its limit points so is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

$S$ is not closed in $\mathbb{Q}$:

Assume it were, then for any sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq S$ which converges to $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ we would have $a \in S$. However, take the sequence $(\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq S$. As a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$, it converges to $0$. However, $0 \not\in S$. Hence $S$ is not closed in $\mathbb{Q}$.

In more detail: Why does $(\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ converge to $0 \in \mathbb{Q}$?

By definition, a sequence converges to $0$ iff for any open neighborhood $N$ of $0$ there exists an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall n \geq n_0: x_n \in N$. Here, since $\mathbb{Q}$ has the subspace topology w.r.t. $\mathbb{R}$, the neighborhoods of $0$ are completely characterized as the open neighborhoods of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, intersected with $\mathbb{Q}$. Furthermore, since in $\mathbb{R}$, every open neighborhood of $0$ contains an open ball, we only need to consider those. So, since we know what the open balls of $\mathbb{R}$ are, we know that $N = \mathbb{Q} \cap B_{\varepsilon}(0)$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$.

And indeed, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb{Q} \cap B_{\varepsilon}(0)$ i.e. $\vert \frac{1}{n} \vert < \varepsilon$.